# Mock NSHTTPURLRequest and NSHTTPURLResponse in iOS unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock, xctest

I'm developing a framework in iOS which makes HTTP calls to server.I wanted to write unit test to test the API's.I wanted to mock the server calls,without actually making real server call.Can anyone help me with sample unit test which makes mocked server calls.How to do we set expectations and return the hand constructed url response.?I'm using XCTest framework for unit test and OCMock for mocking objects.

Comment: With out making actual server call how would you know whether your server is responding as you want?

Comment: @jai : our aim is to mainly test the framework.not server.

Comment: Anyone pls help with some sample unit test for making mocked server calls!.

Comment: How are you making your server calls (i.e. what methods are you using?)

Comment: @BenFlynn : Using NSURLConnection ...

Comment: @Karthik207 That's the class you are using -- which methods? Does my answer below help?

Comment: @BenFlynn: what does handler = [invocation getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:4]; do?? i dont understand the invocation part.

Comment: @Karthik207 I tried to clarify it in an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might mock sendAsynchronousRequest:

```
NSDictionary *serverResponse = @{ @"response" : [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:nil statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:nil headerFields:@{}],
                                  @"data" : [@"SOMEDATA" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                  };

id connectionMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSURLConnection.class];
[[[connectionMock expect] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    void (^handler)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*);
    handler = [invocation getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:4];
    handler(serverResponse[@"response"], serverResponse[@"data"], serverResponse[@"error"]);
}] sendAsynchronousRequest:OCMOCK_ANY queue:OCMOCK_ANY completionHandler:OCMOCK_ANY];
```

**EDIT**

To add clarification, here's what's happening. In this example our real code is calling `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:]` There are three arguments passed to this method, plus the additional `_cmd` and `self` that is passed to all Objective-C method calls. Thus when we examine our `NSInvocation` the argument at index 4 is our completion handler. Since we are simulating the response from the server, we want to call this handler with fake data that represents the case we are testing.

The signature for the method call `getArgumentAtIndexAsObject` is in a header file included with OCMock, but is not included by default in the framework. I believe it is called `NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.h`. It makes fetching the invocation arguments easier by returning an `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Use OHTTPStubs, https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs.

Here's a practical example of mocking the response to a specific GET request and returning JSON data.

```
[OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return [request.URL.path isEqualToString:@"/api/widget"];
} withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse *(NSURLRequest *request) {
    id JSON = @{ @"id": @"1234", @"name" : @"gadget" };
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:0 error:nil];
    return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithData:data statusCode:200 headers:@{ @"Content-Type": @"application/json" }];
}];
```

Comment: Just to save you some time, this works unless you are using the background configuration. From the docs: "OHHTTPStubs can't work on background sessions (sessions created using [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration]) because background sessions don't allow the use of custom NSURLProtocols and are handled by the iOS Operating System itself."